# regex usage in exim filtering

Tags: regular-expression, exim, filter

I'm trying to create an exim filter to block spam messages containing

> " 85% OFF"

in the subject line. That's a blank space, then any two digits, then the percent sign, a blank space and the word OFF in all caps. This is what I wrote:

```
# Exim filter
if
  $header_subject: contains " \\d{2}% OFF"
then
   fail text "no spam please"
   seen finish
endif
```

However, that doesn't seem to work and lets matching messages through, although it passes the [regex101](https://regex101.com/) testing. What am I missing? What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I temporarily replaced my `.forward` file with yours and confirmed that it doesn't work.

There are two problems.

1. `contains` performs a substring match, and does not understand regular expressions. For regexes you want `matches` rather than `contains`.
2. The `\d` PCRE-style character class appears to be broken as does the `{N}` syntax! I tried all kinds of combinations. The only syntax which worked was `[0-9][0-9]`. Even `[0-9]{2}` didn't work, and neither did `[0-9]\\{2\\}`, nor `\\d\\d`. (I'm running version 4.72.) **Edit: Here is the reason:**  Quotes do not have to be used on regexes in Exim filter files, except when regexes contain whitspace. However, backslashes must be doubled up even in unquoted regexes. In quoted regexes, they must be doubled up again: `$header_subject: matches "\\\\d{2}% OFF"`. Count `em: four backslashes.

Test your script with `/usr/sbin/exim -bF <scriptfile> -f <sender>`. A test message must be supplied on standard input (e.g. redirected from a file).

For testing `Subject:` processing, it can contain just that header line and nothing else. The capital `F` in `-bF` is to enable processing of your `fail` command which is disabled if you use `-bf`.

Comment: Quad backslash? What a mess! 
But it did work this time, thank you @Kaz for the time you put into this, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I run an Exim installation so this caught my interest. I use Sieve for filtering of deliveries to my personal inbox, rather than Exim scripts. One reason is that it's a standard language, for which my webmail application (RoundCube) has a plugin, meaning that I (or any other user) can edit their rules from the GUI.

Comment: I know what you mean by mess; I don't understand why Exim doesn't just have a regex literal syntax like `/abc.*\d/`, It feels as if regexes were just bolted into the configuration language as an afterthought.

Comment: Reading the [Exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.91/doc/html/spec_html/ch-regular_expressions.html) for version 4.91+, double (and therefore quad) backslashes are not needed within `Match` statements . I have not tested this .